# Baby want continuously rocking to bouncy

Tags: infant, newborn, siblings

Our baby turned 2 months old and he is lying in bouncy but he wants someone rocking it all the time or else he cries a lot. This is really tiring by hand or by leg.
Why the baby wants so much rocking? He won’t settle on arm rocking. It’s like we have a job of rocking all day long which is exhausting.

Update: Now that he is 4 1/2 months old, things r very much tiring for us. He want to rock, now we make him sit in our lap but he want rocking, this has become a problem as I felt from the stair and hurt my back so I m suffering with serious back pain issue which gets inflamed when I rock the baby bouncy.

The more serious issue is our 4-year son is neglected because we are rocking and carrying out little one all the time. He tries to come and make himself visible and asking for love.

We have raised anxiety between our relation as a husband and wife as my wife is type 2 and get tired spending whole day rocking. What can we do? We tried to sort out a automatic swing bouncy but our son is almost 8 KG and the automatic swinging one is mx of 9kg.

Comment: Have you tried "wearing" the baby (swaddling him to you, esp. skin-to-skin)? Have you tried swaddling at all? What have you tried besides arm rocking? Have you asked his Primary Care Provider? I don't think anyone can answer why your baby likes what he likes. Try different things until you find success or he outgrows this phase. Most babies are exhausting, there's little doubt about that!

Comment: Yes we tired swaddling but nothing won’t work. We tried lying him on tummy that make him silent for 2-3 min that’s all. Rocking all day long will help but this is too tiring and we cannot give time to our 4 yr old.

Comment: Until your baby is older, yes, you have a full time job (at any or all of the 24 hours in the day) rocking, bouncing, feeding, playing, etc. This is normal. This is what you sign up to as a parent, I'm afraid :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop the only  problem I see is that 12 hours of rocking is time consuming so much so that I feel I do not give time to my first child who plays video games, ipad and video games all-day

Comment: @Nofel - correct. That is the challenge all parents face. Solutions include wearing a sling/papoose or holding the baby while giving time to your other child. Or perhaps looking at other things to do with them - computer games all day may not be the best plan here. Can you think of things to do with both children together.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are referring to a bouncy chair, that your son is lying in all day. You (outside of work hours) and his mother should be engaging him in activities. He sounds quite understimulated and yearns for attention, lying in a bouncy chair all day.

A baby requires attention and stimulation throughout every hour they are awake. Furtunately, it can be as simple as bringing them along with your every day activities.

- Doing laundry? Have him sit in the bouncy chair *while maintaining eye contact*.
- Cooking? Have him on your arm, in a swarb on your chest, or in a bouncy chair where he can investigate some of your kitchen utensils.

Play age-appropriate activities with him. Here's one with him having "tummy-time", https://www.webmd.com/parenting/baby/features/tummy-time Yes, he might object, but it will turn for the better - you just have to retry multiple times (but do note to try when he is in a good mood, not when it suits you the best).

You (or his mother) can also engage your older son in playtime, while holding the young one on an arm (or sitting/lying with you), letting the little one investigate a toy. Do note that little one would prefer big brother's toys (a some point), so make sure it is something safe for a baby. Alternatively, have a baby toy among big brother's toy and let the brothers share the toys (again, keep it age appropriate) - this also helps with bonding between them.

Best thing with this is that it would tire the baby, so it would require daytime naps (perfectly normal), thus freeing you and your wife to other activities.

If he only wants to sit in a bouncy chair, being rocked, for 12 hours a day, seek professional help or his primary care practitioner.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Baby Bjorn or other chest/back carrier for the baby? This would allow you to at least be somewhat mobile while pacifying the baby, and it sounds like at least some of the time you are carrying the baby to pacify it already. I've used the Bjorn a lot when going out and its firm/soft back plate will hopefully take the pressure off your back. The ability to have the baby front facing or back facing should hopefully give enough variety for the kid.